# Calling a function from controller to view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a function that returns a string in Controller. So how can i invoke that function when a button is clicked in view?

Comment: What do you want to do with the returned string? Will the string change based on any conditions?

Comment: i want to show it on view when the button is clicked

Comment: CONTROLLER
'
 public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Home/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [WebMethod]
        public static string test()
        {
            
            return "HELLO ";
        }

    }
'

VIEW
I have one input button in view, when i click that it calls the the javascript function which calls test(), and there will be an alert message.

Comment: i think your question is that : In controller you have function and you wont to access that function when u click on button from your view and return data show in your view.right? and tell data which return from controller you wont to show in same view where you click on button or other view ?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this function would be better suited in your model, especially if it perhaps refers to model properties.

Therefore instead of passing a string value to it, this can be accessed within the scope of the function:

```
@(model.Function())
```

If you function is generic, then instead of storing this in the controller, or model, I would recommend storing it in a different class altogether in a seperate namespace:

```
@(Logic.StringFunctions.Function(model.myString))
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, there may be better options, depending on what it is exactly that you're trying to do.  But if your desire is simply to call a method with the click of a button, the simplest way I know of to do that is:

```
<button type="button" onclick="window.location.href='<%=Url.Action("MethodName", "ControllerName") %>'">
```

Hope that helps!